# Putting security to windows form exe file

Tags: winforms, exe

I am working in Windows desktop application using C#. And I want to create a windows setup for the windows application with more secure. And also I know how to create windows setup for windows destop application.

My concern is I want to create a exe file which will be more secure means at the time of installing it will ask a product key. So that if my exe taken away from my system, they shouln'table to use because it will ask product key. Any suggestion how can I implenet in my setup project.

Comment: what kind of "security" ?

Comment: As I mentioned, if my exe is stolen they shouldn't able to use. How do I implement security?

Comment: product key checking will be checking in client side & server side, isn't it?

Comment: @Raptor, could please let me know how to make secure my exe file so that nobody can use without my permission?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are a lot of ways to do so. Simplest way is to verify against server's record by forcing user to login.

Comment: Could you please let me know what are least possibilities?